# React Native FlatList is not rendring an Axios API request

Tags: android, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, react-native-flatlist

I am new to react native , and I am facing a problem with handling props and state ,when i am using redux, I get the data needed for rendering the flat list in the right form but some how the data property inside the flat list only see {this.props.customers} as undefined.
Here is my code:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    debugger;
    this.props.getCustomers();
    debugger;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.customers !== this.props.customers) {
      this.props.getCustomers();
    }
  }


  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.customers}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <View style={styles.GridViewContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>}
          keyExtractor={(x, index) => index}
          numColumns={3}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const customers = state.customers;
  console.log(customers);
  debugger
  return customers;

};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getCustomers
})(CustomersList);
```

And the getCustomers action :

```
export const getCustomers = () => {
    debugger;
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setCustomerLoading)
        axios
            .get('https://calm-sands-26165.herokuapp.com/api/customers')
            .then(res =>
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_CUSTOMERS,
                    payload: res.data,
                })
            )
            .catch(err =>
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: null
                })
            );
    };
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Try to return `{ customers }` instead of only `customers` on your `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: Thank you so much..it works ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mapStateToProps you should return an object, not a value. Each entry in that object will be a prop for the component that's being connected to the store.

In your case, this should be the fix:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const customers = state.customers;
  return { customers };
};
```